# When should I vote to close as "off-topic -> does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community" vs "unclear what you're asking"?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, meta, close-reasons, off-topic

Two of the close reasons here on meta, "Off-topic -> This questions does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community" and "Unclear what you're asking", seem to mean essentially the same thing: we don't see any question to answer. If the question does not appear to seek community input and discussion, then there's really no question to answer, which means "Unclear what you're asking" would also fit.

The only difference I can think of is a total nonsense question, which should be closed as "Unclear what you're asking" rather than "does not appear to seek community input and discussion". This makes me think "does not appear to seek community input and discussion" is a more specific form of "unclear what you're asking", but I don't see why we would have a separate close reason for that.

When should I vote to close as "Unclear what you're asking" vs "Does not appear to seek community input and discussion"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use "Off-topic -> This questions does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community" when the question posted is a rant rather than an objective outlining of an issue.

It may be clear what is being ranted about but the question has been put in a way that is unlikely to lead to constructive discussion of the issue.

Comment: Right. I use the first one for "I got question banned this is unfair, stack exchange sux" and the second for "Why site crash? Get error no work want to ask".